# Shorten only first column in table HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table, with headings in the first column and data in the later columns. It has to fit into a certain width on page, but the all cells are of variable length. Is there any way I can set the first column to shorten itself:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

while leaving the other columns at their full width to show all the data? I have created a demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xsanda/uBrV7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this, but only if you are willing to set a `max-width` of the cell.  The width can't be completely dynamic and still truncated.

http://jsfiddle.net/uBrV7/2/

```
td:first-child {
    max-width: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use max-width: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBrV7/3/)

```
td:first-child {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100px; /* Change this to fit your needs */
}
```